# Filter List in Functional Programming Style

Tags: scala, functional-programming

We have a list of Strings with BEGIN and END marks as parts of this list. Can we filter out elements in-between of BEGIN-END in functional programming style? I came out only with this regular (flag) approach in scala.

```
val list1 =
  """992
  1010
  1005
  1112
  BEGIN
  1086
  1244
  1107
  1121
  END
  1223
  1312
  1319
  1306
  1469""".lines.toList

var flag = false
val filteredList = list1.filter{
  def f(x: String): Boolean = {
    if (x.contains("BEGIN")) {
      flag = true;
      return false
    } else if (x.contains("END")) {
      flag = false
    }
    flag
  }
  f
}
```

Is that possible to avoid defining the flag variable? How do they solve this in pure functional languages?

Comment: You can put the `var flag = false` inside the `filter` block. It’s only half as bad then.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple `BEGIN`...`END` sequences in this list?

Comment: "filter out" was really bad wording if you want the elements between `BEGIN` and `END`.

Comment: Got it. I meant the opposite. Get the elements between BEGIN and END.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `drop`/`tail`, `dropWhile`, `takeWhile` functions:

```
val filteredList = list1.map(_.trim).dropWhile("BEGIN" !=).tail.takeWhile("END" !=)
```

### EDIT

As mentioned in comments `tail` will throw exception if list is empty, so if you prefer to stay on the safe side use `drop(1)` instead of `tail`:

```
val filteredList = list1.map(_.trim).dropWhile("BEGIN" !=).drop(1).takeWhile("END" !=)
```

And here is my version of algorithm that handles several **BEGIN** and **END** sections (some crazy stuff from me - a little state machine :)

```
var filteredList1 = list1.map(_.trim).foldLeft(List(None): List[Option[List[String]]]) {
  case (None :: rest, "BEGIN") => Some(Nil) :: rest
  case (Some(list) :: rest, "END") => None :: Some(list) :: rest
  case (Some(current) :: rest, num) => Some(num :: current) :: rest
  case (result, _) => result
}.flatten.reverse map (_.reverse)
```

it returns `List[List[String]]`

Comment: Rats! Beat me to it as I was typing :)

Comment: Any reason for favouring `drop(1)` over `tail`?

Comment: nope, you are right - tail looks much better (adding change to the answer). Thanks!

Comment: `drop(1)` does not fail on an empty list; `tail` does.  So which is correct depends on the desired behavior if the input is bad.

Comment: @Rex That's the answer I was aiming for :)  It all depends on whether or not a `BEGIN` is guaranteed to be in the input list.

Answer (score 3):

To start with, each string in your list contains the spaces from the start of the line.

This is the biggest problem in your code, and there's two ways to fix it.

Either trim the lines...

```
val list1 =
  """992
  1010
  ...
  1306
  1469""".lines.map(_.trim).toList
```

... or you can precede each line with a `|` and use `stripMargin`.

Then it's just a small matter of applying `takeWhile`/`dropWhile`

```
list1.takeWhile("BEGIN" !=) ++ list1.dropWhile("END"!=).tail
```

or more efficiently:

```
val (begin,middle) = list1.span("BEGIN" !=)
val end = middle.dropWhile("END" !=).tail
begin ++ end
```

**EDIT**

I had the solution back to front, that would drop (filter out) values between `BEGIN` and `END`.  To retain them:

```
list1.dropWhile("BEGIN" !=).tail.takeWhile("END"!=)
```

**EDIT 2**

Rising to the challenge here... I'll allow for multiple BEGIN/END blocks, but also consider that the input might be badly malformed.  What if there was a BEGIN without a corresponding END?  Perhaps there are two BEGINs in  a row, or the list runs out before there's an END.

Defining some rules:

- An END without a corresponding BEGIN is ignored
- BEGIN/END blocks don't nest
- A BEGIN encountered while already in a block starts a new block
- If the list runs out while in a block, then an implicit END is assumed

Without further ado, first create an iterator that identifies every `"BEGIN"` in the input:

```
val blocksStarts =
  Iterator.iterate(list1)(_.dropWhile("BEGIN" !=).drop(1)).drop(1).takeWhile(Nil !=)

//This iterator tries to continue forever,
//returning Nils once the sequences are exhausted
//For this reason, we must use drop(1) instead of tail
```

Giving an iterator of lists, each starting at a `"BEGIN"`

To then take elements from each of these lists until the corresponding `"END"` is reached, or another `"BEGIN"`, or the list is exhausted:

```
val blocks = blockStarts map {
  _.takeWhile(x => x != "BEGIN" && x != "END")
} toList
```

The final `toList` is because it's still an `Iterator` at that point.  You now have a List of Lists, each corresponding to a batch of elements in a "Block", as defined by the previous rules.

Comment: I know the word "filter out" is unclear, but I think you're doing the exact opposite of dmitry's code, and the exact opposite of Easy Angel's code -- you're removing the stuff between `BEGIN` and `END` and they're retaining only the stuff between `BEGIN` and `END`

Comment: Good answer for my challenge. I felt both my solutions were very clumsy. I'll have to learn more ways to use `Iterator.iterate`. I did notice a bug, however, which is that the first element returned by `Iterator.iterate` will be `list1`, so you'll need to add a `drop(1)` before the `takeWhile`.

Comment: Indeed, now fixed.  No more late night postings on SO for me then! (let's see just how long *that* resolution lasts...)

Answer (score 2):

I'm extending others' answers a little to present a case where there are two `BEGIN`...`END` blocks in the list.

```
val list1 =
  """992
  1010
  1005
  1112
  BEGIN
  1086
  1244
  1107
  1121
  END
  1223
  1312
  BEGIN
  773
  990
  224
  END
  1319
  1306
  1469""".lines.map(_.trim).toList
```

We're going to use `foldRight` to pass a status accumulator between iterations.
Note that we're using `foldRight` to make constructing the result list efficient, so we're going to encounter `END` before we encounter `BEGIN`.

```
case class StripStatus(list:List[String], retaincurrent:Boolean)

list1.foldRight(StripStatus(Nil,false)){ (curElem:String, curStatus:StripStatus) =>
   if (curElem == "END")
      StripStatus(curStatus.list,true)
   else if (curElem == "BEGIN")
      StripStatus(curStatus.list,false)
   else if (curStatus.retaincurrent)
      StripStatus(curElem::curStatus.list, true)
   else
      curStatus
}.list
```

We could just as easily use `foldLeft` and `reverse` the result list at the end:

```
list1.foldLeft(StripStatus(Nil,false)){ (curStatus:StripStatus, curElem:String) =>
   if (curElem == "BEGIN")
      StripStatus(curStatus.list,true)
   else if (curElem == "END")
      StripStatus(curStatus.list,false)
   else if (curStatus.retaincurrent)
      StripStatus(curElem::curStatus.list, true)
   else
      curStatus
}.list.reverse
```

Comment: I've got the idea - to pass the result list and flag iterating through the collection.

Answer (score 1):

MMmm. Here's my take:

```
def getInside(l: List[String]) = {
    def concat(in: List[String], out: List[String]): List[String] = in ::: off(out)

    def off(l: List[String]): List[String] = 
        if (l.isEmpty) Nil 
        else on(l dropWhile ("BEGIN" !=) drop 1)

    def on(l: List[String]): List[String] = 
        if (l.isEmpty) Nil
        else (concat _).tupled(l span ("END" !=))

    off(l)
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not tail recursive.

Comment: @Ken True, granted, but how many pairs of BEGIN END are there in the list, for this to be a problem? I do like making things tail recursive, but it was rather difficult here. The mutual recursion is fine -- I even started writing a version with the trampoline code of the library, but the list concatenation...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Scala, but you can define a function that returns the index in the list of the next element that matches a substring, and returns the index where the substring was found and also the list of elements encountered until that substring was matched. A pseudocode header: `findSubstr(list, startIndex)`. Then build the expression (more pseudocode):

```
beginIndex, preBeginElems = findSubstr(list, 0)
endIndex, inBetweenElems = findSubstr(list, beginIndex)
restElems = list[endIndex until the end]
```

If helpful, I could write this in Haskell... :)

EDIT: There are probably other ways to do it, too

Answer (score 0):

Again, with the same goal of dealing with multiple `BEGIN`...`END` spans in the list.

```
def getBetweenBeginEnd(l:List[String]) = {
   def internal(l:List[String],accum:List[String]):List[String]={
      val (keep, keepChecking) = l.dropWhile("BEGIN" !=).drop(1).span("END" !=)
      if (keepChecking == Nil)
         accum:::keep
      else
         internal(keepChecking.tail,accum:::keep)
   }
   internal(l,Nil)
}
```

Comment: the `drop(1)` can't be replaced with `tail` here, because `Nil.drop(1)==Nil`, but `Nil.tail` throws an exception.